# Leaflet.js - Fit geoJSON co-ordinates on map view

Tags: javascript, geojson

I have a leaflet.js map that has points and linestrings on it that come from an external JSON file.

If I add:

```
map.setView(new L.LatLng(0,0), 10);
```

It will centre the map on the latitude and longitude 0,0. How can I set it so the map centre and zoom fit all of the points from the JSON on it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could add all of your layers to a FeatureGroup which has a `getBounds` method. So you should be able to just say `myMap.fitBounds(myFeatureGroup.getBounds());`

The getBounds method for L.FeatureGroup is only available in the master branch (not the latest version, 0.3.1), for now at least.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. So if at the minute my code that adds the geoJSON layer looks like:

    geojsonLayer.addGeoJSON(jsonData);
    map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
    map.fitBounds(jsonGroup.getBounds());

I would change it to:

    geojsonLayer.addGeoJSON(jsonData);
    map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
    var jsonGroup = new L.FeatureGroup(jsonData);
    map.fitBounds(jsonGroup.getBounds());

And that should work?

Comment: Sorry, it has stripped all of the formatting out of my post above and I'm not sure how to preserve it when I save the comment.

Comment: It's pretty tough to debug in the comments. Can you paste your code over at http://jsfiddle.net to show me what you've got (or at least part of it)?

Comment: Here is a link to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/pq4KV/. The only thing missing is the contents of the JSON file (data.php) because all of that code is on a local server. I can upload an example geoJSON file if you need it.

Comment: You guys were on the right track, but all you had to do was call .getBounds() on the geojsonLayer.  It extends from the FeatureGroup.  http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson

Comment: getBounds() both on geojson or on Feature group gives me an error that bounds do not exist

Answer (score 6):

Similar case with me. I drawn all the *markers* from *GeoJson* data. So I written the  function, which gets called repeatedly on button click. Just try if it suits your requirements.

```
   function bestFitZoom()
    {
        // declaring the group variable  
        var group = new L.featureGroup;

        // map._layers gives all the layers of the map including main container
        // so looping in all those layers filtering those having feature   
        $.each(map._layers, function(ml){

           // here we can be more specific to feature for point, line etc.            
            if(map._layers[].feature) 
             {
                 group.addLayer(this)
             }
         })

         map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
    }
```

The best use of writing this function is that even state of map/markers changed, it will get latest/current state of markers/layers. Whenever this method gets called all the layers will be visible to modest zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this when showing a user directions from his origin to a destination.  I store my list of directions in an array of `L.LatLng` called `directionLatLngs` then you can simply call

```
map.fitBounds(directionLatLngs);
```

This works because `map.fitBounds` takes a `L.LatLngBounds` object which is just an array of `L.LatLng`

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds